# Can't access applications page with my account

Tags: facebook

I can't access https://developers.facebook.com/app with my pages account - I get redirected back to profile page. How to access my application?

I've already created one and could not access it anymore!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant access the developers tools when you are browsing as a page... You can only use those tools when you are logged in as a "real" user.

Comment: OK. But I somehow managed to CREATE an app under this account. As a proof, I got a "Message for Developers Only" when access this page: https://apps.facebook.com/330826596932845. (It is used only for sharing in iPhone app, so I don't need a Canvas URL)

Comment: The link you gave shows a message saying that the application is misconfigured.  You simply can not create an application with anything other than a "real" account.  Facebook will not allow it.  Applications have to be associated with "real" accounts so that facebook can contact the developer if any problems are found.